# ReactiveObject OnDeserialized throws security exception

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight-5.0, reactiveui

I have ReactiveObject as my ModelBase class, I am using silverlight client and WCF service built on .net 4.0 at server side.

My ReactiveUI_SL5 assembly version is 4.0.2, when making service call I am getting runtime exception that Can't Deserialize

Message I am getting is 
SecurityException unhandled.
Message= the data contract type reactiveUi.reactiveobject cannot be deserialized because ondeserialized method setupRxObj is not public.

**How to make it working?** 
**Where can I get latest versoin of ReactiveUI_SL if this has been fixed?**

May be I am using any older version but can't find any latest version than 4.0.2 for silverlight, while installing using nuget also getting error below
**Could not install package 'Splat 1.3.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework**

Comment: Probably best to not send a object that inherits from ReactiveObject. I generally create a minimal class (POCO) that it is purely there for sending from client to server and vice ce versa.

Comment: Source of ReactiveObject has declared it as DataContract but all of property is marked as [IgnoreDataMember] but because it is reactive and I am using stateless viewmodel pattern I have ReactiveObject is my BaseModel class. Is there any way it can be ignnored from serializing without changing its source code?

Answer (score 0):

I Realised that there is no support of reactive ui for Silverlight from version 4.6.7 so downloaded source code from https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/rxui4 and added

Silverlight condition to ReactiveObject's setupRxObject method.

```
    [OnDeserialized] //Added Silverlight here
#if WP7 || SILVERLIGHT
    public
#endif 
    void setupRxObj(StreamingContext sc) { setupRxObj(); }
```

Recompiled and worked.